# Rails bypass timeout for database maintenance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application which contains a model = `workorder`.

The database contains 22,468 workorders that have a `wonum` starting with `13-`.  I would like to delete them.  `workorder` has several tables with `has-many`, so I would like to do it programatically vs. trying to use SQL directly against the database.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
<div class="span11">
  <h4>Records Deleted: </h4>
  <%= Workorder.where("wonum like ?", "13-%").count %>
  <%= Workorder.where("wonum like ?", "13-%").destroy_all %>
</div>
```

I'm running this code on my Mac using Webbrick.  Once I have the database cleaned up, I will upload it to Heroku.

The problem I'm having is that the code takes a long time to run and I'm getting timeout errors.

Questions:

1) Is this a logical way to clean up the database?

2) How can I bypass any timeout for this code?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because all of the records are being loaded into memory. Try processing in [batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html):

```
Workorder.where("wonum like ?", "13-%").find_each { |wo| wo.destroy }
```

As Brad mentioned, you can use `delete_all`, but only do that if you don't need to remove any associated models.

To answer (2), no this is not a logical way to clean up the database (using links on the frontend). Create a `rake` task, or interact with the database from the console (run `rails console`).